# Read Json from firebase to Google graph

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I have a json file from firebase that gives 2 main titles AB and AC <- these are temperature sensors that send the temp every 10min.

Now I want to show these values in highcharts but i'm having problems to cascade down the json.

I know there are a lot of similar questions I have read all of them.

```
{
  AB: {
    BattLevel: {},
    temperature: {
      -K9XTKDOM-SlhChO8mla: {
        date: "02/02/2016",
        time: "15:53:23",
        value: "009.4"
      }
    },
AC: {
    BattLevel: {},
    temperature: {
      -K9XR29RmWhy0bt353uf: {
        date: "02/02/2016",
       time: "15:43:26",
        value: "008.2"
    },
```

This is a piece of the code to fill the google graph table.

```
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('datetime', 'Tijd');
            data.addColumn('number', 'kotje');
            data.addColumn('number', 'buiten');

            $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                data.addRow([
                    (new Date(row.date)),
                    parseFloat(row.value),   <--- here i should get to AB
                    parseFloat(row.value)    <--- here i should get to AC
                ]);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to navigate the JSON.

```
Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
  var row = results[key];
  var temperatures = row.temperature;
  Object.keys(temperatures).forEach(function(tempKey) {
    var temperature = temperatures[tempKey];
    console.log(temperature.date + ' ' + temperature.value);
  });
});
```

There are probably easier way, but this one works and uses only plain JavaScript constructs.

```js
var results = {
  AB: {
    BattLevel: {},
    temperature: {
      "-K9XTKDOM-SlhChO8mla": {
        date: "02/02/2016",
        time: "15:53:23",
        value: "009.4"
      }
    }
  },
  AC: {
    BattLevel: {},
    temperature: {
      "-K9XR29RmWhy0bt353uf": {
        date: "02/02/2016",
        time: "15:43:26",
        value: "008.2"
      }
    }
  }
};

var output = document.getElementById('output');
  
Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
  var row = results[key];
  var temperatures = row.temperature;
  Object.keys(temperatures).forEach(function(tempKey) {
    var temperature = temperatures[tempKey];
    output.textContent += temperature.date + ' ' + temperature.value + '\n';
  });
});
```

```html
<pre id='output'></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am realising this doesn't solve the graphing problem i am having. i'll post a new question.